# Create a document from several NSStrings using UIDocumentInteractionController

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have several NSStrings like this:

```
@property (nonatomic, copy,   readonly) NSString          *browserName;
@property (nonatomic, copy,   readonly) NSString          *browserVersion;
@property (nonatomic, copy,   readonly) NSString          *browserMajor;
@property (nonatomic, copy,   readonly) NSString          *operatingSystemName;
```

How would I take those strings and make a document that I can share, email, copy, etc using a UIDocumentInteractionController

I already have the document controller displaying in my app, I just don't know how to populate a file with the info off of those strings.

Let me know if you need more details or have questions

Comment: What kind of document do you want to create from the text? A PDF? A text file? What?

Comment: @rmaddy .txt file would awesome

Comment: Append the strings and write the string to a text file.

Comment: Ok I'll search for examples of what that would look like

Comment: @rmaddy would you happen to have some example code, or could show me what that would look like?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8645237/how-to-write-content-in-text-file-in-objective-c-iphone?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

Here is how I did it:

```
NSArray *visitorInfoArray = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Visitor Location", _visitor.location, @"currentURL", _visitor.currentURL, nil];
    NSString *visitorInfo = [visitorInfoArray componentsJoinedByString:@" "];

    NSString *filename = @"User Info";
    NSURL *tempURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[NSTemporaryDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename]];
    [visitorInfo writeToURL:tempURL atomically:YES encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];
    [MTq main:^{
        [FCIProgress dismiss];
        DLog(@"%@", visitorInfo);
        self.documentInteractionController = [UIDocumentInteractionController interactionControllerWithURL:tempURL];
        self.documentInteractionController.UTI = @"public.plain-text";
        [self.documentInteractionController presentOptionsMenuFromBarButtonItem:sender animated:YES];
    }];
```